# invoking newInstance on package-protected class's ctor

Tags: java, reflection, default-constructor

I have a package-protected (default) class

```
package a;    
class Foo {}
```

So implicitly, it'll have a package-protected constructor.

Now if I have a reference to `Constructor<Foo> fooCtor = ...`;

Should I not get some kind of exception if I try to invoke `fooCtor.newInstance()` outside of `package a`?

Comment: As I understand it, the constructor itself is `public`. You can't access it because it's inside a `package-private` class.

Comment: What happens when you try?

Comment: It let me invoke the constructor w/o any exception!

Comment: OK, so you have the answer to your question.

Comment: I'm assuming the question is *why?*.

Comment: How did you obtain the constructor instance? Can you post a self-contained example?

Comment: How ware you able to use `Constructor<Foo>` outside `a` package if `Foo` is not public class? I suspect that this code is placed inside `a` package and that is why everything works fine.

Comment: @Pshemo: you're right, if `Constructor<Foo>` compiles without errors it implies that `Foo` is accessible. And if it's accessible, reflective construction will succeed.

Comment: @Holger other possibility is that there is another `Foo` class used instead of `a.Foo` which is either public or placed in same package as this code.

Answer (score 1):

You can't create an instance of the class unless you change the constructor's accessibility. If your `Foo` class is as following:

```
package org.visib.a;
class Foo {
  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "This is a foo";
  }
}
```

You can try instantiating a `Foo` but will get an `IllegalAccessException`, e.g., try:

```
package org.visib.b;
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
public class FooCreator {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, InstantiationException {
    Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("org.visib.a.Foo");
    for (Constructor<?> c : clazz.getDeclaredConstructors()) {
      System.out.println("Found constructor: " + c);
      Object foo = c.newInstance();
      System.out.println(foo);
    }
  }
}
```

However, you can change the access modifier of the constructor. Just add the following line in the for loop:

```
c.setAccessible(true);
```